# Creating unwanted allocations/ failing to release allocations

Tags: cocoa, memory-management, malloc, allocation

I am having a problem releasing my allocations. My allocations tool in my instruments indicates that "bitmapData = malloc( bitmapByteCount );" is the source of the allocation and that it is not being released. I am new to cocoa and xcode. How would I correct this problem and prevent the code below from using more and more memory? I appreciate the help. Thanks

```
#import "imagewell.h"

@implementation imagewell

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.



        NSString *path =@"/Users/ethansanford/Desktop/mutable string logic/mutable string logic/long-arrow-right.png" ;
        CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename(path.fileSystemRepresentation);
        imageRef2 =CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(provider, NULL, false, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
        CGDataProviderRelease(provider);


    }
    return self;
}


-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent{

    NSPoint point = [theEvent locationInWindow];//where image was tapped
    [self convertPoint:point fromView:nil];
    clicks = clicks+ 1;
    colorpt=[self getPixelColorAtLocation:point];
    [self SetPixelColorAtLocation:point withColor:[NSColor redColor]];

    NSPoint pointz = NSPointFromCGPoint(CGPointMake(200, 100));




    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];

}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect{

      CGContextRef myContext;
    myContext = [NSGraphicsContext.currentContext graphicsPort];

    imageRef = imageRef2;
   // NSLog(@"%@ %zu",@"height",CGImageGetHeight(imageRef));
        NSLog(@" %@ %f %f %f %f ", @"color1 argb", colorpt.alphaComponent*255, colorpt.redComponent*255, colorpt.greenComponent*255, colorpt.blueComponent*255);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(myContext, colorpt.CGColor);
    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(0,0, 100, 100);
    CGContextFillRect(myContext,rectangle);
    CGContextDrawImage(myContext, dirtyRect, imageRef);


}


- (NSColor*) getPixelColorAtLocation:(NSPoint)point {
    NSColor* color1 = nil;



    // Create off screen bitmap context to draw the image into. Format ARGB is 4 bytes for each pixel: Alpa, Red, Green, Blue
    CGContextRef cgctx = [self createARGBBitmapContextFromImage:imageRef];
    if (cgctx == NULL) { return nil; /* error */ }

     w = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    size_t h = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
    CGRect rect = {{0,0},{w,h}};

    // Draw the image to the bitmap context. Once we draw, the memory
    // allocated for the context for rendering will then contain the
    // raw image data in the specified color space.
    CGContextDrawImage(cgctx, rect, imageRef);

    // Now we can get a pointer to the image data associated with the bitmap
    // context.


    data = CGBitmapContextGetData (cgctx);
    bitmap_info_of_context = CGBitmapContextGetBitmapInfo(cgctx);
    bits_per_component_of_context = CGBitmapContextGetBitsPerPixel(cgctx);
    bytes_per_row_of_context = CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow(cgctx);
    width_of_context = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    height_of_context = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);



    if (data != NULL) {
        //pos_in_array locates the pixel in the data from x,y.
        //4 for 4 bytes of data per pixel, w is width of one row of data.
        int pos_in_array = 4*((w*round(point.y))+round(point.x));
        int alpha =  data[pos_in_array];
        int red = data[pos_in_array+1];
        int green = data[pos_in_array+2];
        int blue = data[pos_in_array+3];
        //NSLog(@"pos_in_array: %i colors: RGB A %i %i %i  %i",pos_in_array,red,green,blue,alpha);
        color1 = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:(red/255.0f) green:(green/255.0f) blue:(blue/255.0f) alpha:(alpha/255.0f)];
    }

    // When finished, release the context
    CGContextRelease(cgctx);
    // Free image data memory for the context



    return color1;
}



- (CGContextRef) createARGBBitmapContextFromImage:(CGImageRef) imageRef {


    CGContextRef    context = NULL;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    void *          bitmapData;
    int             bitmapByteCount;
    int             bitmapBytesPerRow;

    // Get image width, height. We'll use the entire image.
    size_t pixelsWide = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    size_t pixelsHigh = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);

    // Declare the number of bytes per row. Each pixel in the bitmap in this
    // example is represented by 4 bytes; 8 bits each of red, green, blue, and
    // alpha.
    bitmapBytesPerRow   = (pixelsWide * 4);
    bitmapByteCount     = (bitmapBytesPerRow * pixelsHigh);

    // Use the generic RGB color space.
    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    if (colorSpace == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating color space\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Allocate memory for image data. This is the destination in memory
    // where any drawing to the bitmap context will be rendered.
        bitmapData = malloc( bitmapByteCount );



    if (bitmapData == NULL)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", @"shit");
        CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );
        return NULL;
    }

    // Create the bitmap context. We want pre-multiplied ARGB, 8-bits
    // per component. Regardless of what the source image format is
    // (CMYK, Grayscale, and so on) it will be converted over to the format
    // specified here by CGBitmapContextCreate.
    context = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmapData,
                                     pixelsWide,
                                     pixelsHigh,
                                     8,      // bits per component
                                     bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                     colorSpace,
                                     (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    if (context == NULL)
    {

        fprintf (stderr, "Context not created!");
    }

    // Make sure and release colorspace before returning
    CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );

    return context;
    CGContextRelease(context);






}

-(void)SetPixelColorAtLocation:(CGPoint)location withColor:(NSColor*)replacement{

    if (data != NULL) {
        //pos_in_array locates the pixel in the data from x,y.
        //4 for 4 bytes of data per pixel, w is width of one row of data.
        int pos_in_array = 4*((w*round(location.y))+round(location.x));
        data[pos_in_array]= 255;
        data[pos_in_array+1] = 0;
        data[pos_in_array+2] = 255;
        data[pos_in_array+3] = 0;
        //NSLog(@"it happened");


        CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        CGContextRef context=  CGBitmapContextCreate(data, width_of_context, height_of_context, 8, bytes_per_row_of_context, colorspace, (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

        imageRef2 = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
        CGContextRelease(context);
    }

}



@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `malloc()` memory you are (usually) responsible for latter calling `free()` to release it. However from the documentation for `CGBitmapContextCreate`:

> In iOS 4.0 and later, and OS X v10.6 and later, you can pass NULL if you want Quartz to allocate memory for the bitmap. This frees you from managing your own memory, which reduces memory leak issues.

So in this case you should be able to remove the `malloc()` and pass `NULL`.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I was failing to release the CGImage object. 
releasing it prevented the leak. 
I avoid global variables now that can be used in multiple methods.